# how to use required attribute on properties that can be hidden in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Scenario: The user should fill out a form and based on his choices different properties are displayed(using jquery .show and .hide). 
Problem: I want some of those properties that are shown to be required(but only when they are shown ofc). The [Required] attribute doesn't care if the property is shown or not. So if I use [Required] the user are asked to fill out properties he can't see.
Solution: ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [RequiredIf attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) to perform conditional validation:

```
[RequiredIf("HiddenFoo", "true", ErrorMessage = "Foo is required")]
public string Foo { get; set; }

public string HiddenFoo { get; set; }
```

Now, add a hidden field called `HiddenFoo` and then toggle its value when you are showing/hiding the `Foo` textbox. `Foo` will be required only if `HiddenFoo="true"`.